# 親ディレクトリに存在するパッケージのimportに失敗する

Tags: python

ディレクトリは以下のように構成されています。

```
.
├── mod_a
│   └── main.py
└── mod_b
    ├── __init__.py
    └── cls_b.py
```

また各ファイルの中身は以下のようになっています。

main.py

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../')

from mod_b import ClsB

print(ClsB.hello())
```

mod_b/__init__.py

```py
from .cls_b import ClsB
```

mod_b/cls_b.py

```py
class ClsB:
    @staticmethod
    def hello():
        return 'Hello Cls B'
```

この状態でmain.pyを実行すると、mod_bが見つからないという旨のエラーが発生します。

```
> py mod_a/main.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod_a/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mod_b import ClsB
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_b'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mod_a/main.py", line 4, in <module>
    from mod_b import ClsB
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mod_b'
```

`sys.path.append('../')`によってmod_bはimportの検索対象に入っていると思うのですが、なぜうまくimport出来ていないのかが分かりません。

main.pyからmod_bパッケージを読み込む方法を教えて下さい。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`> py mod_a/main.py`ということで、起動時のディレクトリが、まさにその親ディレクトリだから、それを起点にさらに親ディレクトリに探しに行っているようです。

以下のどれかのパターンで出来るでしょう。
もっと良いやり方はあるでしょうが、それは他の人に。

- `mod_a`ディレクトリに降りて`py main.py`と実行する
- `sys.path.append('../')`を`sys.path.append('./')`に変更する
- `import os`して、`sys.path.append('../')`を`sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../')`に変更する
- `import os`して、`sys.path.append('../')`の前に`os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))`を記述する

参考：
[Pythonで実行中のファイルの場所（パス）を取得する__file__](https://note.nkmk.me/python-script-file-path/)